# Java - How to replace Negative Lookbehind?

Tags: java, regex, negative-lookbehind

I've found many guides on how to replace regex phrase to Lookbehind, but not on how to reverse-engineer it, I was wondering if there was a certain system in Java?
for example for the next phrase `(?<!\\)'(.*?)(?<!\\)'`
What would be the way to make it a regex without negative lookbehind?

Comment: Are you sure that the second look-behind is supposed to be a look-behind, not a look-ahead? Transforming this regex into one without look-behind is no big deal (incorporating nong-capturing groups). As far I I understand, the reex means "Look for a string in single quotations, if there is no \ before the single quotations.

Comment: What are you trying to match? Please, give some examples.

Comment: for example: “This ’isn\’t’ easy’” the method should return the single string “isn’t" or input: "more'test'" Expected: test